# Give access of horizontal scroling plugin to user role editor

Tags: plugins, user-access

How do i give access to user role editor without using any plugin using bellow function

```
function HSA_add_to_menu() 

    {

        add_options_page('Horizontal scrolling announcement',  __('Horizontal Scrolling', WP_hsa_UNIQUE_NAME), 'manage_options', 'horizontal-scrolling-announcement', 'HSA_admin_options' );

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> function HSA_add_to_menu() 
>
>     {
>
>         add_options_page('Horizontal scrolling announcement',  __('Horizontal Scrolling', WP_hsa_UNIQUE_NAME), 'edit_others_posts', 'horizontal-scrolling-announcement', 'HSA_admin_options' );
>
>     }
> ```
>
> http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Editor

Comment: its showing two menus of plugin if put both and old code and if put this code only its showing message don't have permission to access this page

Comment: @SanjayNakate Put code with "edit_others_posts" and then login as editor and try.

Comment: i did but adminisrator canot use this plugin after putting this code

Comment: The capabilities parameter of `add_options_page` only controls the display of the menu item. The function that displays the content of the options page should also be checking capabilities and if you can see the menu item but not access it, you need to check the capabilities restriction of that function.

Comment: good answer finally its working for both admin and editor user roles